# how to set up SQL/Hive connection with cloudera cluster to read data stored on cluster

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-streaming

I wanted to retrieve the data stored onto Hadoop Cloudera cluster either via Hive, Spark or SQL. I have SQL query written which should fetch data from the cluster.
But prior to that, I want to understand how to set up connection /Cursor with cluster so that it will know where to read from or write to?

`sc = spark.sparkContext` or similarly HIVECONTEXT or SPARKCONTEXT will not suffice.

We might need to give URL for node and all. So how to do that?

Any Small example would suffice.

Comment: If you want to query the data through hive you will have to define the schema so make hive table first load the data into that table and then run queries like SQL and you basically define the source and destination address while creating the table in the hive  in order to figure out where to write and read from .

Comment: exactly I agree, I just need example for "you basically define the source and destination address while creating the table in the hive in order to figure out where to write and read from"

Comment: Please find the example below and let me know if you still need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create the table in the hive:

1- Creating an external table schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names_text(
          student_ID INT, FirstName STRING, LastName STRING,    
          year STRING, Major STRING)
          COMMENT 'Student Names'
          ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
          STORED AS TEXTFILE
          LOCATION '/user/andrena';
```

2- a) Create the schema for a managed table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Names(
  student_ID INT, FirstName STRING, LastName STRING,    
  year STRING, Major STRING)
  COMMENT 'Student Names'
  STORED AS ORC;
```

b) Move the external table data to the managed table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Names SELECT * FROM names_text;
```

And finally, verify that the Hive warehouse stores the student names in the external and internal  table respectively :

```
SELECT * FROM names_text;

SELECT * from Names;
```